# Makefile build subdirectories by name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a golang monolith repo with multiple apps in it. I have Makefile in each app root and I have to be in the app directory like `root/app1/` to run `make build`. I want to get rid of these identical Makefile's in each service and have a top level Makefile that I can use to build all apps at once each creating individual executables or build specific app only. Something like

```
make build app1 # builds only app1
make build # builds all apps
```

Obvious way to achieve this is to have targets for all apps and have build commands, but wanted to know if there is an easier way to do this by just not even repeating that build command per target in Makefile

Comment: In your makefile, what is the name of the default target?

Comment: In my individual apps its "build"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to move the Makefile up to `root/` and add these lines at the top of it:

```
APPS := app1 app2 ...
TARGETS := $(addsuffix /build, $(APPS))

all: $(TARGETS)

%/build:
    $(MAKE) -C $* -f ../Makefile build
```

If you don't want to use Make recursively, then we must see the internals of your makefile in order to see how to modify it.